# Running mvn clean install app tries to connect postgres to wrong port

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven

I get this error when running

```
$ mvn clean install

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432
refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Yet on my application.properties I have clearly defined the port as 5433:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/mydb
```

I am also running postgres on port 5433 stated in postgres.conf:

```
port = 5433                             # (change requires restart)
```

I did run

```
$ systemctl postgresql restart
```

after changing the port.

What is wrong here?
I didn't define the port anywhere else in my project files.

Full application.properties file:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypass

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

Comment: It's clear that your app does not use the configuration you think it should use

Comment: I am sure that in a spring-boot project there is no other place to set port for postgres than the application.properties file. Only thing I can think of, is that the value is stored somewhere on the previous runs.

Comment: On a side note: why does your build process need Spring to connect to the DBMS at all?

Comment: @Amadán I dont understand your question. I have a springboot project where i use postgres db to save sport event scores. I am failing to connect to it during build, because maven build uses different port that I have defined.

Comment: Could you add your pom.xml ?

Comment: @SampoKaarenmaa Why does your application run during build? Are you running integration tests during build? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your configuration file (which you haven't provided). If you are using spring boot you most likely have a java file for it instead of an xml one and in it you have to call your property from the application.properties file.

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;
```

You should have a @Bean definition for the data source which should look something like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    return dataSource;
}
```

The problem is you are either not setting the url to what you've specified in the application.properties file or you're overwriting it somewhere down the line.

***EDIT**

```
@Configuration
public class PostgreConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver_class_name}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have such I file. I define these in the application.properties. From which I only included the necessary file "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/mydb"

Comment: Is a "DataSource" file needed? The program compiles properly.

Comment: Yes, to overwrite the auto configuration you need a file annotated with Configuration in which you define the dataSource Bean. It compiles because when you have a postgres dependency it automatically searches on the default postgres port - 5432.

Comment: I have postgres dependency as follows: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: I have added the class you need as an edit to my answer. You'll have to define the rest of the properties in you application.properties file as well and you should be able to reach the db.

Comment: Configurations set in Java bean class solves my problem. Apparently application.properties file is not enough. Eventough the required settings(port and login) are set there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the cmd
2. Write `netstat -ao | find "5433"`
3. You will get

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8089           DESKTOP-Q687KK9:0      LISTENING       7732
```

We use port **7732**

4. execute this command `Taskkill /pid 7732 /F`

output: `SUCCESS: The process with PID 7732 has been terminated.`

5. run `systemctl postgresql restart`

Comment: For clarification i use Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Also i believe systemctl restart postgresql does the same thing.